# WebRTC : Video black screen bitrate

Tags: webrtc

Is the bit rate of black screen shown when video is muted same as the original video's bit rate or is it significantly less because it is just a black screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across `chrome://webrtc-internals`, which has inbuilt tracking for bit rates and has other good features. [image]

As seen in graph, bit rate before video was muted was ~150k which reduces to ~30k on muting the video.

Comment: Oh I forgot about that! webrtc-interals is also using the stats/reports I mentioned. So you'd get the same information.

Answer (score 2):

It is significantly less. Since there is essentially no video information being sent to the remote party. How much depends on a lot of factors (connection quality etc).

I just did a quick test and the outgoing bit rate at `640x480 @ 27fps` was around `900 kbps` to `1 mbps`. Disabling the video track of the stream resulted in an outgoing bitrate of `30 kbps`.

Please keep in mind that this was only a simple test I did. You can get this kind of information yourself by evaluating the reports in `peerConnection.getStats`

Some documentation and libraries for getStats

- https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats
- https://github.com/muaz-khan/getStats
- https://www.callstats.io/2015/07/06/basics-webrtc-getstats-api/